# Question not displaying close votes properly?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179850/how-do-i-tell-my-internet-browser-to-save-a-batch-file-instead-of-viewing-it

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I've refreshed a few times.  The visible close vote is mine.  Unless sgtdck typed that in manually and 4 people actually upvoted it, which seems unlikely, I think there might be something wrong.

Comment: Voting on comments requires 15 reputation, while close-voting requires 3,000.

Comment: ahh, so he really did type it manually!

Comment: That user probably flagged the question as a duplicate (which will also automatically generate a comment). Then other users with less than 3k probably also flagged the question as a duplicate of that question (which will automatically upvote that comment).

Comment: So if you don't have enough rep for close-vote it still adds the comment but just no vote?  Okay, now I understand and have learned something new!  Thanks.

Comment: I actually used to type that in manually until I got the flagging privilege and figured out it would do it automatically if you flag it before writing the comment itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The user flagged the question. This still generates the auto-comment, but as I understand it, the flags do not show up next to the "close" link. They do still show up in the close vote menu.

If you hover over a user's username on a comment they've posted, you'll see their reputation:

[image: Rep shown on hover]

As you can see, the user in question does not have the 3k rep required to close vote- But they *do* have the 50 rep necessary to *flag* as duplicate.

Regarding the upvotes on the comment, which you also touch on in your question, it could be three things:

1. Users could legitimately just be upvoting the comment. I've done this myself when I agree that a question is a duplicate, but see zero point in flagging it as duplicate. (Since it's already been flagged/closed voted, why should I flag it again?)
2. Users could have also flagged the question, with the same duplicate. This would automatically upvote the comment, rather than posting a second one. A new automatic comment would only be posted if a different link was proposed.
3. Close votes also automatically upvote the possible duplicate comment, if the vote is for the same link. Since your image shows only one true close vote, and that is yours, it's pretty safe to assume that, in this case, that's not where the other four upvotes came from. (At the time of writing this part, this could be where more of the upvotes came from. There are currently 8 on the comment, rather than 5.)

Comment: Damn these off-by one errors